# Android AudioFocus with AudioTrack hardly works

Tags: java, audio, audiotrack

I use **AudioTrack** to play some audio like GPS navigation does. Of course, I need to ask for an audio focus, but my ugly code doesn't make the trick as I expected. I hear the audioTrack sounds, but I can't say that the music player (another application) reduces it's volume.

**AudioTrack**:

```
audioTrack = new AudioTrack.Builder()
    .setAudioAttributes(new AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
            .build())
    .setAudioFormat(new AudioFormat.Builder()
            .setChannelMask(AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO)
            .setEncoding(AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT)
            .setSampleRate(SAMPLE_RATE)
            .build())
    .setTransferMode(AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM)
    .setBufferSizeInBytes(intBufferSize)
    .build();

audioTrack.play();
```

**Playback and focus request:**

```
maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

AudioAttributes playbackAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
    .build();
AudioFocusRequest focusRequest = new AudioFocusRequest.Builder(AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK)
    .setAudioAttributes(playbackAttributes)
//      .setAcceptsDelayedFocusGain(true)
//      .setOnAudioFocusChangeListener(afChangeListener)
    .build();


int afresult = audioManager.requestAudioFocus(focusRequest);
Log.d(TAG, "Music request focus, result: " + afresult);

if (afresult == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Audio Focus is granted ");

    audioTrack.setVolume(maxVolume*0.4f);
    audioTrack.write(myAudioData, 0, myAudioData.length);
}

else if (afresult == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_FAILED){
    Log.d(TAG, "Audio Focus is failed ");
} else if (afresult == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_DELAYED){
    Log.d(TAG, "Audio Focus is delayed ");
}

audioManager.abandonAudioFocusRequest(focusRequest);
```

I don't have `OnAudioFocusChangeListener` yet, but I will implement it. So why does it seem like that other applications don't handle audio focus loss? `AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT` works, but `AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK` doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that my code can't be working as I am trying to mute one music stream and play another one. I had to change `USAGE` and `CONTENT_TYPE` attributes.

It can be `CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION` + `USAGE_ASSISTANCE_SONIFICATION` or `CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH` + `USAGE_VOICE_COMMUNICATION` as it is said in [documentation](https://source.android.com/devices/audio/attributes).

Hope, it will help somebody.